# Create Test using Xray REST API and link to Test Set

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I am trying to create a test using Xray REST API. At the time of creation, I am also trying to add the test case to a test set which already exists.

This is my input json for the POST.

```json
{
 "fields":
 {
   "project":  {"key": "TEAM"}
   ,"summary": "Sum of two numbers-1"
   ,"description": "example of manual test-1"
   ,"issuetype": { "name": "Test" }
   ,"customfield_23240": { "value": "Manual" }
   ,"customfield_23244": {
      "steps":[
          { "index": 0, "step": "Step 1",
             "data": "input Data 1",
             "result": "Excepted result 1"
          },
          {  "index": 1, "step": "Step 2",
             "data": "input Data 2",
             "result": "Excepted result 2"                     
          },
          {  "index": 2, "step": "Step 3",
             "data": "input Data 3",
             "result": "Excepted result 3"                     
          },
          {
             "index": 3, "step": "Step 4",
             "data": "input Data 4",
             "result": "Excepted result 4"                     
          }
     ]}
   , "customfield_23246": { "set": [ "TEAM-12" ] }   
 }
}
```

I have double-checked the customfield ids and they are correct.

This is the command I am running

```bash
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
     -X POST --data @test-1.json  
     -u user:pwd https://myserver/rest/api/2/issue
```

But I am getting http 500 error.

```json
{"errorMessages":["Internal server error"],"errors":{}}
```

Am I doing something wrong or am I doing something which is not supported by API. It is not clear to me from Xray documentation.

Answer (score 1):

After a long trial and error exercise, finally found the correct json to be posted.

This `"customfield_23246":{"set":["TEAM-12"]}` was changed to `"customfield_23246":["TEAM-12"]`

This is the correct input json.

```json
{
 "fields": {
    "project": { "key": "TEAM" }
    ,"summary": "Sum of two numbers-1"
    ,"description": "example of manual test-1"
    ,"issuetype": { "name": "Test" }
    ,"customfield_23240": { "value": "Manual" }
    ,"customfield_23244": {
         "steps":[
                {
                  "index": 0,"step": "Step 1",
                  "data": "input Data 1",
                  "result": "Excepted result 1"}
               ,{
                  "index": 1, "step": "Step 2",
                  "data": "input Data 2",
                  "result": "Excepted result 2"}
               ,{
                  "index": 2,"step": "Step 3",
                  "data": "input Data 3",
                  "result": "Excepted result 3"}
               ,{                
                  "index": 3, "step": "Step 4",
                  "data": "input Data 4",
                  "result": "Excepted result 4"                     
                }
            ]
        }
    ,"customfield_23246" : ["TEAM-12"]              
   }
}
```